# Spinner muestra lista de elementos pero no deja seleccionar ningún elemento

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código:
tengo una lista la cual le voy pasando el elemento test para hacer una prueba.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner spinner;    
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    getData();
}

public void getData(){
    String sql = "http://link.local";

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    try {

        url = new URL(sql);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        String json = "";

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        json = response.toString();

        JSONArray jsonArr = null;

        jsonArr = new JSONArray(json);
        String mensaje = "";
        //ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,)
        for(int i = 0;i<jsonArr.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

            Log.d("SLIDA",jsonObject.optString("Usuario"));

            items.add("test");

        }

        //sal.setText(mensaje);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que selecciono un elemento del Spinner pero no lo muestra en la barra. He probado spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); pero con esto ni se me abre la APP.

Fotos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Alguna idea... ?**

Comment: comenta esta linea `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);`

Comment: Buenas Igmer, comentando la línea tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

items.add(0,"Selecciona un elemento");
items.add("elemento1");
items.add("elemento2");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Selecciona un elemento"))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcMiw16bouA